# Why does this flutter app fail to build dependencies of flutter_playout?

Tags: flutter

As I understand it, the problem is with the version flutter_playout ^1.0.25
Replacing the required v1.0.36 one gives nothing
Maybe something is wrong, or something is missing?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Could not determine the dependencies of task ': flutter_playout: compileDebugAidl'.
    > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ': flutter_playout: debugCompileClasspath'.
       > Could not find: android_malibrary :.
         Searched in the following locations:
           - file: /Users/annashcherbak/Documents/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_playout-1.0.36/android/libs/android_malibrary.aar
         Required by:
             project: flutter_playout
       > Could not find: exoplayer_AkamaiMediaAnalytics :.
         Searched in the following locations:
           - file: /Users/annashcherbak/Documents/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_playout-1.0.36/android/libs/exoplayer_AkamaiMediaAnalytics.aar
         Required by:
             project: flutter_playout

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Here's the result of `flutter doctor`

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G73, locale ru-RU)
     
    [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
        ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
    [!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.6)
        ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
            CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage
            on the Dart side.
            Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
            For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
          To install:
            sudo gem install cocoapods
    [✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    [✓] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
    [✓] Connected device (1 available)
    
    ! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
    if (flutterRoot == null) {
        throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
    }
    
    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }
    
    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "selena.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

              minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Comment: Have you run `flutter pub get`? Please provide your `gradle.build` files from app and package level as well.

Comment: flutter pub get tried it, nothing helps.

Comment: as I understand the problem with the plugin flutter_play version 1.0.36
I have version 1.0.25 installed, but for some reason the application build began to require 1.0.36
I installed it but nothing helps, all the necessary files are in the file folder. This problem is on Mac, on Windows there is no such problem, version 1.0.25 is there, and there are others in the project folder, but the collector does not swear at them and works quietly with version 1.0.25

Comment: Are the flutter and android sdk version equals on both systems (PC, Mac)? I had a similar issue when I set up my CI/CD on my build server because there were "minor" version differences on my dev PC and the build server itself.

Comment: On both platforms, the versions are exactly the same, 1.12.13+8hotfix

Comment: Same here in Windows using VSCode and Android Studio. Only happens with 1.0.36, 1.0.35 works fine